# Managing opened ODS spreadsheet via Python

Tags: python, automation, openoffice-calc

It is possible to access a live, currently opened MS Office document via API like `getActveXObject()` and then manipulate it programmatically: read and write cell values, modify their visual properties.

Is there such possibility for Open Office ODS spreadsheets? An Python API is preferrable.

P.S. I don't want to embed my script into a document or OO, it gonna be a separate piece of software.

OS: macOS; Linux is available too

Comment: google "python ODS document API"

Comment: https://onesheep.org/scripting-libreoffice-python/

Comment: http://christopher5106.github.io/office/2015/12/06/openoffice-libreoffice-automate-your-office-tasks-with-python-macros.html